# Trying to access string array, saying it's empty even though its full

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I'm having a problem when i'm trying to access the text that i have stored in a string array. I know, the problem seems so easy, but I just can't figure out where i'm going wrong...

So when i'm console logging the contents of the array to the browser, I can see that i get values as follows:

```
console.log(myStringArray)

output:
10[...]
 0: "a lot of text here"
 1: "also here"
 2: "and here... etc"
 ...
```

But when i'm trying to access the values like:

```
myStringArray[0];
```

The result i'm getting is a one slotted array with nothing in it like:

```
(1)[...]
 0: ""
 length: 1
 >_proto__: Array[]
```

Trying to convert the result into strings etc didnt work so well either.
Could someone help me access these values, thanks!

**Edit:**
The text that i'm getting is articles from wiki:s API.

```
  function getMoreText(){
   for(let j = 0; j < titlesInSearch.length; j++){
        textContent[j] = [''];

        textUrl = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&prop=extracts&exintro=&explaintext=&titles=' + titlesInSearch[j];

        $.getJSON({
            url: textUrl,
            dataType: "jsonp",
            success: function(data, status, xhr) {
                var page = data.query.pages;
                var pageId = Object.keys(page)[0];

                if(page[pageId].title == titlesInSearch[j]){

                    textContent[j] = page[pageId].extract;
                }

             }
     })

}
}
```

and when i'm console logging the values, when i'm going to update the HTML code, the result are as I explained above:

```
function updateGUI(){
//resetting when getting new articles
document.getElementById("artikel").innerHTML = '';

//getting the result
console.log(textContent);

//not getting anything
console.log(textContent[0]); 

for(let b = 0; b < titlesInSearch.length; b++)
{   
    console.log(textContent[b]);
    if(summary[b].includes("may refer to:")){
        console.log("filtered: 'may refer to'") //do nothing
    } 
    else if(summary[b] != ''){
        document.getElementById("artikel").innerHTML += ('<div>' + textContent[b] +'</div>');  

    }
}    

}
```

Comment: I guess you will need to post a real example. Right now it is too hard to tell exactly what is the problem

Comment: Please post the context. As we can only guess what the problem is, I'd say it's an async issue.

Comment: The console displays a dynamic value of sorts of your object, maybe your array is still getting filled while you are logging it. Please post a [mcve] of the function that fills your array

Comment: How `myStringArray` looks like in raw code, not in `console.log`?

Comment: updated the question

Comment: Your call to `$.getJSON()` is wrong. It doesn't take an object with options, that's the way to call `$.ajax()`.

Comment: You need to call `updateGUI()` from the `$.getJSON()` callback function.

Comment: Thank you Barmar! Read about "Asynchronous code" (which i've never heard about before) and "understood" that it had to go there :)

Answer (score -1):

First add to url `&origin=*` other way you will get error from wiki

> Failed to load
>   https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&prop=extracts&exintro=&explaintext=&titles=java:
>   No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. If an opaque
>   response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to
>   fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

Secondly you need to wait for data before you get access to them.
If you want to store them in `textContent = []` array will by empty if you will read it before you finish connection with http://wiki.api and get response.

You can rewrite second function to work in place `readData(singleContent)` and work with one item at the time. This way you don't need to wait for every response from wiki.

This is in vanilla javascript, but in $.getJsons or $.ajax idea is the same.

```js
/* jshint node: true */
//var fetch = require('node-fetch')
var titlesInSearch = ['java', 'linux']
var textContent = []

function getMoreText(){
  "use strict"
  titlesInSearch.forEach(function(searchItem){
    var url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&prop=extracts&exintro=&explaintext=&origin=*&titles=' + searchItem
    return fetch(url)
      .then(function(response){
        return response.json()
      })
      .then(function(data) {
        var page = data.query.pages;
        var pageId = Object.keys(page)[0];

        var singleContent =''
        if (page[pageId].title.toUpperCase === searchItem.toUpperCase) {
          singleContent = page[pageId].extract
          textContent.push(singleContent.substring(0,50)) //short str
        }
        readData(singleContent)
      })
  })
} 
getMoreText()

function readData(singleContent){
  "use strict"
  // read data one by one
  console.log(singleContent)
  console.log('-----------------------------')
  console.log(textContent) // array 
}
```

Notice console.log('----------'), you will see interesting thing. While you getting single `singleContent` and how array `textContent` looks on every request(how many items it have).

Comment: This is a comment on the original post. Please remove this answer or edit it to provide an actual answer.

Comment: Yeah... you guys have right, now should by ok